# DbUpdateConcurrencyException ao tentar atualizar dados com Entity Framework

Tags: banco-de-dados, .net, entity-framework, linq

Olá, estou tentando atualizar dados do banco mas estou enfrentando um problema que até então nunca tinha visto. Normalmente uso essa abordagem para atualizar dados, mas dessa vez surgiu esse erro e gostaria de entender melhor o motivo e como resolvê-lo:

```
//essa entidade tem uma chave primária composta por 3 colunas no banco de dados
var exists =  await _context.Relatives
    .Where(x => x.Company== companyId)
    .Where(x => x.Person== personId)
    .Where(x => x.Cpf == familiar.Cpf)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

if (exists != default)
{
    exists.Cpf = familiar.Cpf;
    exists.Nome = familiar.Name;
    //restante dos dados, são vários
}

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Ao executar o `SaveChangesAsync()`, surge esse erro: `Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 43 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded`. Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender melhor em qual parte do meu caso está gerando esse erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução encontrada: o problema estava sendo causado por uma má configuração de uma chave primária composta. A chave primária está sendo configurada em `OnModelCreating` do contexto da aplicação, inicialmente estava sendo disposto os múltiplos campos individualmente.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Table>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("ABC");
    entity.HasKey(x => x.Key1);
    entity.HasKey(x => x.Key2);
    entity.HasKey(x => x.Key3);
});
```

Dessa forma, ao executar uma atualização, a query gerada pelo Entity Framework gerava apenas um `WHERE`, o que implicava em vários registros, a maneira correta seria a seguinte:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Table>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("ABC");
    entity.HasKey(x => new
    {
        x.Key1,
        x.Key2,
        x.Key3
    });
});
```